# Animating with Auto Layout and iOS7 jumps to end of animation (fine in iOS6)

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, autolayout, constraints

I am using Autolayout and animating by changing the constraints, however, in iOS7 the view simply jumps to the end position - in iOS6 I get a nice animation.

Is should be noted these views are UICollectionViews and I have checked the Storyboard and there are no Layout errors.

All I can think is there is something and am or am not setting on the Storyboard or something that I am doing wrong with the Constant settings in the Storyboard.

```
primaryMenuYContraints.constant = BUTTOMX;;
leftMenuYContraints.constant = 136.0f;
leftMenuBottomConstraint.constant = 5.0f; 

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^
                 {

                     // Move in menus
                     [self.primaryOptionCollection layoutIfNeeded];
                     [self.menuOptionCollection layoutIfNeeded];


                 }
                completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {


                 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed to and now works in both iOS7 and 6, still not sure why it does/did it though!  I still think I am setting something up wrong in the Storyboard.  I am add another view (nothing to do with this lot) programmatically so I believe that is based around frames until I convert it (which I am not doing).

```
primaryMenuYContraints.constant = BUTTOMX;;
leftMenuYContraints.constant = 136.0f;
leftMenuBottomConstraint.constant = 5.0f; 

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                  delay:0.0f
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
             animations:^
             {

                 // Move in menus
                 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];


             }
            completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {


             }];
```